# Cannot find "Integration Services" on my Visual Studio 2019 while the extension was installed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition, and Visual Studio 2019 Community Version. And then I also installed "Data Storage and processing" just the same as this step described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Unfortunately, when I check the extension in my Visual Studio, I see the "Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Projects" checked, but when I created a new project, and tried to search for Integration Services, I just could not find any matched result. I have tried to modify the Visual Studio 2019 several times by checking "Download all and then install all" and restart the Visual Studio 2019. So far my attempts all failed.

Can anyone provide me with any suggestions?

Comment: The SSIS project extension is a [separate download and install](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects), not managed by the the VS 2019 installer or extensions manager.

Comment: I knew about this. I did both the downloads. Yesterday I installed VS 2019 Enterprise Trial version and it worked. Thank you very much anyways!